# How to close the shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shadow box, and it contains a form , the problem is when the form is submitted shadow box doesn't get closed.I've used these functions , 
self.close();
window.parent.Shadowbox.close();

but still no luck, can any one help me, thanks

This is how I created the shadow box

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Example shaodow box</a>

<script language="javascript">

    $('#mylink').click(function(){

        Shadowbox.open({

            content:    'mybox.php',
            player:     'iframe',
            height:     550,
            width:      800,

            options: {

                onClose: function() {
                    top.location = "index.php?mydata=asas1234";                 
                }

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context around this. how is this shadow box created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `ShadowBox.init({...})` before calling other methods.